# How do I convert a string into a DateTime without overwriting it OR modify the string without having to convert it?

Tags: php, datetime

So I'm trying to make the code echo the date for the last saturday of february of the chosen year, but the method I attempted using completely overwrote the value of the string. I need the string to keep its value but still modify it into telling me the last saturday of february.

Heres the code:

´´´
<?php

```
$valdatum = date ("y-m-d H:i T", 0);

if(isset($_POST["valdatum"])) {
    $valdatum=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valdatum', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <title>Tjejvasan</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="date" name="valdatum" value="<?= $valdatum;?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
        </form>
    <?php
    echo $valdatum;
    echo "<br>";
    $valdatum = new DateTime;
    $valdatum->modify('last saturday of february');
    $valdatum2 = $valdatum->format('Y-m-d');
    echo $valdatum2;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

´´´

Comment: `the chosen year`...isn't happening. Your form asks the user to enter a whole date, not a year. Do you actually want the user to input a year, or do you want them to input a date, and your code should then extract the year from that date value?

Comment: `the method I attempted using completely overwrote the value of the string`...well yes, you re-used the same variable name again and re-assigned it.

Comment: @ADyson So basically I need the date from the input type date to always be the last saturday of february, but is there a way to make that happen without having to modify the string. So I basically just want the year to stay from the input type date whilst it also echoes the last saturday from the february of the chosen year. I'm pretty new to coding so I'm really not good at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have tied yourself in a few knots. I *think* this is what you need, although your description is not 100% clear:

```
if(isset($_POST["valdatum"])) {
    //use the date value submitted from the form
    $valdatum = $_POST["valdatum"];
}
else
{
  //use today's date when nothing else was submitted
  $valdatum = date("y-m-d");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <title>Tjejvasan</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="date" name="valdatum" value="<?= $valdatum;?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Skicka">
        </form>
    <?php
    //change the date to the last saturday in February of the same year
    $febDate = new DateTime($valdatum);
    $febDate->modify('last saturday of february');
    echo $febDate->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```